# What is the proper way to handle exception user input in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I'm pretty new to python, and want to know what would be the best way to handle exceptions with user input. I have two examples that I've come up with during my study

Example 1:

```
def userInput():
while True:
    try:
        balance= float(raw_input("What is your balance: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter valid input!"
        continue
    try:
        interestR= float(raw_input("Please enter interest as decimal: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter valid input!"
        continue
    try:
        payRate= float(raw_input("Please enter min payment rate as decimal: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter valid input!"
        continue

    return balance, interestR, payRate
```

Example 2:

```
def userInput():
while True:
    try:
        balance= float(raw_input("What is your balance: "))
        interestR= float(raw_input("Please enter interest as decimal: "))
        payRate= float(raw_input("Please enter min payment rate as decimal: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter valid input!"
        continue
return balance, interestR, payRate
```

I'm asking for three inputs. In the first example, if the user enters invalid information for one of the three inputs, they'll only have to repeat for that specific input. In the second example, if the user enters invalid input in any of the three, they'll have to restart all three inputs. What would be best practice when handling exceptions with user input. Should I have a standalone function for user input? Is there a cleaner way to code this? Sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: *"If you need to ask your user for a lot of different values, it might be useful to put this code in a function, so you don't have to retype it every time."*

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the duplicate I should have searched better.